# Setting the Desired resolution of Mobile Handset Camera in J2ME

Tags: image, java-me, parameters, resolution

I have an application using Nokia X2 which is 5 MPix camera. I need images only for 2 MPix. So I changed the settings on Phone to 2 MPix. When I take a snap by using Phones Camera application, I am getting a 2 MPix image. However, when I activate the camera through my J2ME Code, it gives me an image with 5 MPix. Any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the resolution for the camera through the API. It should look like something below.

```
cameraControl = (CameraControl)player.getControl("CameraControl");
cameraControl.setStillResolution(1)
```

You can read the supported resolutions with

```
int []res = cameraControl.getSupportedStillResolutions();
```

the the index of the returned array (res) is the value you set to [CameraControl#setStillResolution()](http://library.forum.nokia.com/topic/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-D3E35E6F-0C45-48ED-B09D-F716E14C1C02/javax/microedition/amms/control/camera/CameraControl.html#setStillResolution%28int%29)